# Python dictionary union not working as expected with dictionaries of depth greater than 1

Tags: python, dictionary

Here is an example to illustrate the problem...

```
a = {
    "foo" : 2,
    "bar" : 3,
}

b = {
    "bar" : 4,
    "zzz" : 5,
}

print(json.dumps(dict(a, **b), indent=4))
```

This gives you the following result...

```
{
    "foo": 2,
    "bar": 4,
    "zzz": 5
}
```

Notice how the `"foo"` key from `a` was added to the result?

Now look at this example...

```
a = {
    "foo" : {
        "1" : {
            "foo" : True,
        },
        "2" : {
            "foo" : True,
        },
        "3" : {
            "foo" : True,
        },
        "4" : {
            "foo" : True
        }
    }
}

b = {
    "foo" : {
        "1" : {
            "foo" : True,
        },
        "2" : {
            "foo" : True,
        },
        "3" : {
            "foo" : False,
        }
    }
}

print(json.dumps(dict(a, **b), indent=4))
```

This gives you the following result...

```
{
    "foo": {
        "1": {
            "foo": true
        },
        "3": {
            "foo": false
        },
        "2": {
            "foo": true
        }
    }
}
```

`"3"` was updated just like how `"bar"` was updated in the previous example but notice how the `"4"` key from `a` was not added to the result like how `"foo"` was in the previous example?

So my expected output would be:

```
{
    "foo": {
        "1": {
            "foo": true
        },
        "3": {
            "foo": false
        },
        "2": {
            "foo": true
        },
        "4": {
            "foo": true
        }
    }
}
```

How can I modify this dictionary union process so that keys in `a` that are not in `b` are retained?

My overall goal is to have my dictionary `a` but with any values that are in `b` overridden.

Comment: So what are you expecting to get? Give us an expected output for your current example.

Comment: @abccd I'm expecting to get that final result I posted but with the `"4"` key in it as well.

Comment: IIRC the folks at Webpack have a config merger which acts on js objects which look quite a lot like dicts.  Don't let the config/webpack trappings fool you, it's really a deep merger.  I'd love to see it in python. https://github.com/survivejs/webpack-merge

Answer (score 2):

Let's talk about this behave. I think the critical point is how `**kwargs` works.

In your first case, when you pass `**b` to `dict()`, it is the same as `dict(a, bar=4, zzz=5)`. So under this situation, `{zzz: 5}` was added into dictionary, and `{bar: 4}` was updated.

But in your second case, when you pass `**b` to `dict()`, it is the same as `dict(a, foo={...})`. As the `foo` parameter override the same key in `a`, the result is absolutely the same as `b`. So it is not an **update** action but an **override** action.

Take another example:

```
a = {
    "foo" : {
        "1" : {
            "foo" : True,
        },
        "2" : {
            "foo" : True,
        },
        "3" : {
            "foo" : True,
        },
        "4" : {
            "foo" : True
        }
    }
}

b = {
    "foo" : {
        "1" : {
            "foo" : True,
        },
        "2" : {
            "foo" : True,
        },
        "3" : {
            "foo" : False,
        },
        "5" : {
            "foo" : False,
        }
    }
}

print(json.dumps(dict(a, **b), indent=4))

output:
{
    "foo": {
        "1": {
            "foo": true
        },
        "2": {
            "foo": true
        },
        "3": {
            "foo": false
        },
        "5": {
            "foo": false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh I see, so the `**` operator is not recursive, it only operates on the top level keys. I can see why its not working but this isn't exactly a solution to my overall problem.

Comment: @Ogen I know what you really want, it is `deep merge` which is a common topic, just search it or see duplicated question in your question's comment.

Answer (score 1):

For your specific case, that there's only a `dict` depth of one, you can just use a loop and call `dict.update()` to update the values. The reason your's doesn't work is because `dict(a, **b)` overrides all the duplicate keys `a` and `b` shared in common and only keeps `b`'s, which means that `a`'s `"foo"` was completely replaced by `b`'s `"foo"`

```
import json

for k in a.keys():
    try:
        a[k].update(b[k])
    except KeyError:
        continue

print(json.dumps(a, indent=4))
```

This will achieve your desired result `"1" ,"2" ,"3"` being updated from `dict` `b` and `"4"` being kept from `dict` `a`. But if you have a dict with n depth, that will not exactly work. You will need to use a recursive function, as followed:

Sample data:

```
a = {
    "foo" : {
        "1" : {
            "foo" : {"1": True,
                     "2": False},
        },
        "2" : {
            "foo" : True,
        },
        "3" : {
            "foo" : True,
        },
        "4" : {
            "foo" : True
        }
    },
}

b = {
    "foo" : {
        "1" : {
            "foo" : {"1": True,
                     "3": True},
        },
        "2" : {
            "foo" : True,
        },
        "3" : {
            "foo" : False,
        }
    }
}
```

Recursive code:

```
import json

def update(dctA, dctB):
    if isinstance(dctA, dict) and isinstance(dctB, dict):
        for k in set(dctA.keys()) & set(dctB.keys()):
            update(dctA[k], dctB[k])
            try:
                dctA[k].update(dctB[k])
                dctB.pop(k)
            except (KeyError, AttributeError):
                continue
    return dctA

print(json.dumps(update(a, b), indent=4))
```

The output will be:

```
{
    "foo": {
        "1": {
            "foo": {
                "1": true,
                "2": false,
                "3": true
            }
        },
        "2": {
            "foo": true
        },
        "3": {
            "foo": false
        },
        "4": {
            "foo": true
        }
    }
}
```

Which as you can see, the `"3"` key got updated with `"foo"` changing to `false`, and `"4"` being kept as `dict` `b` doesn't update key `"4"`. Furthermore, thanks to the recursion function, the nested `"foo"` key also been updated, `{"1": True, "2": False}` with `{"1": True, "3": True}` updated to `{"1": true, "2": false, "3": true}`. The `"1"` stayed the same, `"2"` was kept because `dict` `b` does not have key `"2"`, and key `"3"` was created because it is present in `dict` `b`.